# Pop_os 19.10 doesn't suspend

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, suspend

It doesn't matter what suspend method I use (desktop, `sudo systemctl suspend`, `pm-suspend` etc.), it doesn't work. Just shows a blank screen (sometimes completely black, depending on suspend method used) and isn't responsive to any keyboard or mouse event. I'm having to shutdown laptop by holding the power button for some time.

**Laptop**: HP ENVY - 13-aq1006ur

**OS**:

```
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="19.10"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Pop!_OS 19.10"
VERSION_ID="19.10"
HOME_URL="https://system76.com/pop"
SUPPORT_URL="http://support.system76.com"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://system76.com/privacy"
VERSION_CODENAME=eoan
UBUNTU_CODENAME=eoan
LOGO=distributor-logo-pop-os
```

`journalctl -b -1 | tail -100`:

```
Mar 22 13:35:43 pop-os gnome-shell[2004]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/pop-suspend-button@system76.com/extension.js 205]: assignment to undeclared variable gnomeShellVersion
Mar 22 13:35:43 pop-os NetworkManager[949]: <info>  [1584869743.6509] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Mar 22 13:35:43 pop-os NetworkManager[949]: <info>  [1584869743.6511] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 22 13:35:43 pop-os NetworkManager[949]: <info>  [1584869743.6520] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Mar 22 13:35:43 pop-os gnome-shell[1298]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Mar 22 13:35:44 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Succeeded.
Mar 22 13:35:44 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Mar 22 13:35:44 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Succeeded.
Mar 22 13:35:45 pop-os blueman-mechanism[2396]: Exiting
Mar 22 13:35:46 pop-os systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 22 13:35:46 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 22 13:35:46 pop-os systemd-sleep[2669]: Suspending system...
➜  ~ journalctl -b -1 | tail -100
```

Currently using Nvidia. Tried switching to Intel and Hybrid Graphics, but problem remained the same.

Also tried

```
sudo kernelstub -a "button.lid_init_state=open"
```

suggested elsewhere to no result.

I noticed one a similar problem of one kind or another online, but really nothing much helpful. What else can I check to debug the problem?

**Screen lock works fine.**

Answer (score 1):

I think its a hardware issue, you can find out by trying the following:-

List Devices:-

```
sudo grep enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

You should get a list like this:-

[image]

You need to go through them and disable them, switch to sudo:-

```
sudo su
```

Trying disabling the first in the list with the following command:-

```
 echo GP12  > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Now try suspend.... if it starts back up from suspend try the next, maybe try a few at a time for speed.  Once you locate the item(s) you need to persist changes after a reboot.  Create the following file:-

```
/etc/systemd/system/disable-hardware-wakeup.service
```

Add the following code into it...

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/disable-hardware-wakeup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

now create another file:-

```
/usr/local/disable-hardware-wakeup.sh
```

Add the following code into it, based on the device which won't allow your computer to sleep, in my case **GPP0**

```
#!/bin/sh

for device in GPP0
do
    if grep -q "$device.*enabled" /proc/acpi/wakeup
    then
        echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup
    fi
done
```

Make the shell script executable:-

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/disable-hardware-wakeup.sh
```

Enable the service:-

```
sudo systemctl enable disable-hardware-wakeup.service
```

Go and say thanks to Vegard Skjefstad -> https://www.vegard.net/how-to-suspend-pop-os/

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: The images are for reference only - to explain what appears onscreen - you can copy and paste the commands.

Comment: But as the link explains, the images are not searchable and may not be readable by all users. If the reference information is useful to the answer you should make it available to all users. Since you used the output contained in the image in the subsequent commands you should make that output available.

Comment: I don't see how the images cause a problem, like I said, they are only for reference, the question has been open for a long time and I thought I would answer it, I provided a text answer and not just a hyperlink if the answer is not helpful flag it as such.

Comment: The link explains multiple ways that images can cause a problem. If you choose to ignore best practices on this forum that is your decision.

Comment: ok, I see that and I will  go easy on pictures in future